# Pic 16f84 + rs232 problema al enviar valor superior a 0x79

Tags: programación-bajo-nivel, ccs, pic

mi primer post en español, tengo un problema al enviar datos a un pic a través de 232...

Lo tengo probado en físico y virtual(proteus) y en ambos ocurre igual...

Cuando trato de enviar un valor **0x80** o superior, lo que se envía es siempre un **0x3f**, y no me explico el porqué.

Cuando envío valores entre  **0** y **0x79** todo va bien.

Para enviar el dato he probado con hyperterminales ajenas y tambien otro programa en vbstudio que funciona bien con otros micros... 
Y todas responden igual.

He aquí el código, cuya función es un simple echo, y establecer el valor recibido en el puerto B.

```
#include <16F84.h> 
#fuses XT,NOWDT,NOPROTECT 
#use delay(clock=4000000)  
#use rs232(baud=9600,parity=N,xmit=PIN_A1,rcv=PIN_A0,bits=8)  
unsigned int rx; 

void main (){  
set_tris_b(0b00000000);
set_tris_a(0b00000001); 

  while(true){ 
     rx=getc();    
printf("%x\r\n", rx);  
 output_b(rx);  
  }}
```

Dado todo esto me da a pensar que algún fuse del pic? es muy raro, al principio pensé que era por declarar la variable **rx** como un simple **int** en vez de un **unsigned int** , pero tampoco funcionó.

Puede alguien ayudarme con esto? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Acuérdate que después del `0x79` viene `0x7a`, `0x7b`, `0x7c`, `0x7d`, `0x7e`, `0x7f` y `0x80`

Comment: ... gracias pero es igual, el problema sigue igual

Comment: `PORTA` tiene un ancho de 5 bits, prueba con `set_tris_a(0b00001);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El codigo del pic esta bien, el problema esta en la parte vb.net, encontre esto y me ayudo mucho.

Extended SerialPort Windows Forms Sample

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Extended-SerialPort-10107e37
el problema es que enviaba ascii en vez de bytes hex

gracias a todos

Comment: Gracias por compartir la solución. ¿Puedes incluir en tu pregunta la etiqueta `vb.net`? Para que quede más claro, y además para tener un ejemplo, ¿puedes incluir también el fragmento de código que causaba el problema, junto con la solución?